# Homology of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $E \subset \mathbb R^n$. Must the homology groups $H_k (E)$ be trivial for $k \geq n$? How about just for $k > n$? If not, whats an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://www.logic.info.waseda.ac.jp/~eda/index.html

Comment: @Ryan: Nice counterexample! I would have thought that the ‘dimension’ of a subspace would be bounded by the ‘dimension’ of the space, but I guess pathological subspaces can behave badly...

Comment: @Ryan: are there also counterexamples for $k>n$? are the higher singular homology groups of the (n-1)-Hawaian earring known?