# $S^n$ is not homotopy equivalent to any subspace $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Is it true that the sphere $S^n$ is not homotopy equivalent to any subspace $\mathbb{R}^n$? How to prove it?

I thought to take advantage of the fact that $H_n (X) = 0$ for any subspace $\mathbb{R}^n$, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94618/homology-of-subsets-of-mathbb-rn) is [not true](http://www.logic.info.waseda.ac.jp/%7Eeda/index.html). As is known, the situation with homotopy groups is [even worse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres).

Comment: It should be subset, I think, not subspace.

Comment: ["subspace"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) is correct. It means subset with the induced topology.

Comment: @DreamAR Hmm, what's the difference? As far as I know, people say both. If we argue about this, then, it seems to me, strictly speaking, a subset is a set (an object of the Set category), and a subspace is a subset with an induced topology (an object of the Top category).

Comment: @AivazianArshak Sorry, I confuse subspace and (linear) subspace.

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649728/can-a-subset-of-mathbbrn-be-homotopy-equivalent-to-sn?rq=1

Comment: @DreamAR Thanks a lot! Sorry that I accidentally asked the already resolved question (strange that MSE didn't find it when I entered the title). Probably the question should be closed or deleted?